# Loading dblink.sql in Postgres 8.4

Tags: postgresql, dblink, pgadmin

I found good article in dblink http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html, but got stuck on loading dblink.sql. 
Can anyone give me information on loading the dblink.sql into the database.
I am using pgAdmin III on a Postgres version 8.4.

Thank you

Comment: I got the solution, its really simple. Feel stupid to ask this question.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 1):

psql -d "database_name" < "dblink_location"/dblink.sql